# A dobut regarding SSH Key and GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

a question regarding GitHub and SSH.

So I am trying out the first-contributions project on GitHub , trying to learn fork,clone etc

Cut to the chase , I saved my ssh key (was told to made it cause git-push was resulting in authentication failure) on the clone of the first contributions directory.

This is the step :

> When you're prompted to "Enter a file in which to save the key", you can press Enter to accept the default file location.

Link : https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Although I can't seem to find it in the folder I saved in  , I tried ls -la and it's not there.

I haven't pushed the changes in the branch I created cause it's failing but I wanted to know , my ssh won't be exposed right?
If the file isn't the directory , it won't be pushed into Github right?

Comment: your ssh keys are by default stored under -  ~/.ssh/ directory.
you can check them by ls  ~/.ssh/

your ssh keys won't be exposed as they're not stored inside your cloned project.